# Error trying to install php-gd

Tags: wordpress, bash, centos

Trying to resolve a problem in which [Wordpress won't generate thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/thumbnails-not-generating-upon-new-image-upload), I tried and failed to install php-gd.
Now I think I've screwed everything up.
I've seen two similar questions in [other sites](https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/print.php?form=1&topic_id=25881&forum=38&order=ASC&start=0) but I just don't know where to begin and I'm very afraid of screwing up things even worse. I'm sorry for the dumb question.

```
Last login: Wed May 25 11:29:20 on ttys000
victorgonzalez@localhost: ~ $ ssh root@ttamayo.com
Last login: Tue May 24 22:44:06 2011 from
############################################################
                     (mt) shortcuts
############################################################

To see your Plesk password, type: p

To rebuild your Apache/Web Server configuration, type: web

To rebuild your Qmail/Mail Server configuration, type: mchk

To see your Qmail/Mail Server queue, type: q

To completely restart your Qmail/Mail server, type: r

To connect to your MySQL server as admin, type: my

To get rid of these messages/aliases, edit your /root/.bash_profile

[root@ttamayo ~]# yum install php-gd
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
 * addons: mirror.rackspace.com
 * atomic: www6.atomicorp.com
 * base: mirror.vcu.edu
 * extras: hpc.arc.georgetown.edu
 * updates: mirror.batblue.com
addons                                                   |  951 B     00:00     
atomic                                                   | 1.9 kB     00:00     
atomic/primary_db                                        | 523 kB     00:00     
base                                                     | 1.1 kB     00:00     
extras                                                   | 2.1 kB     00:00     
updates                                                  | 1.9 kB     00:00     
updates/primary_db                                       | 463 kB     00:00     
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-gd.i386 0:5.3.6-3.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.3.6-3.el5.art for package: php-gd
--> Processing Dependency: libt1.so.5 for package: php-gd
--> Running transaction check
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.2.6-1.el5.art for package: php-odbc
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.2.6-1.el5.art for package: php-imap
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.2.6-1.el5.art for package: php-pdo
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.2.6-1.el5.art for package: php-mhash
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.2.6-1.el5.art for package: php-ldap
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.2.6-1.el5.art for package: php-mysql
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.2.6-1.el5.art for package: php-xml
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.2.6-1.el5.art for package: php-mcrypt
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.2.6-1.el5.art for package: php
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.2.6-1.el5.art for package: php-snmp
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.2.6-1.el5.art for package: php-xmlrpc
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.2.6-1.el5.art for package: php-cli
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.2.6-1.el5.art for package: php-mbstring
---> Package php-common.i386 0:5.3.6-3.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package t1lib.i386 0:5.1.2-2.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libXaw.so.7 for package: t1lib
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libXaw.i386 0:1.0.2-8.1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libXmu.so.6 for package: libXaw
--> Processing Dependency: php = 5.2.6-1.el5.art for package: php-devel
---> Package php.i386 0:5.3.6-3.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package php-cli.i386 0:5.3.6-3.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libedit.so.0 for package: php-cli
---> Package php-imap.i386 0:5.3.6-3.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package php-ldap.i386 0:5.3.6-3.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package php-mbstring.i386 0:5.3.6-3.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package php-mcrypt.i386 0:5.3.6-3.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libltdl.so.3 for package: php-mcrypt
---> Package php-mysql.i386 0:5.3.6-3.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16 for package: php-mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16) for package: php-mysql
---> Package php-odbc.i386 0:5.3.6-3.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package php-pdo.i386 0:5.3.6-3.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package php-snmp.i386 0:5.3.6-3.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package php-xml.i386 0:5.3.6-3.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package php-xmlrpc.i386 0:5.3.6-3.el5.art set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libXmu.i386 0:1.0.2-5 set to be updated
---> Package libedit.i386 0:3.0-2.20090923cvs.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package libtool-ltdl.i386 0:1.5.22-7.el5_4 set to be updated
---> Package mysql-libs.i386 0:5.1.57-1.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package php-devel.i386 0:5.3.6-3.el5.art set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package           Arch      Version                          Repository   Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 php               i386      5.3.6-3.el5.art                  atomic      1.3 M
     replacing  php-mhash.i386 5.2.6-1.el5.art

 php-common        i386      5.3.6-3.el5.art                  atomic      970 k
     replacing  php-ncurses.i386 5.2.6-1.el5.art

Updating:
 php-gd            i386      5.3.6-3.el5.art                  atomic      205 k
Installing for dependencies:
 libXaw            i386      1.0.2-8.1                        base        324 k
 libXmu            i386      1.0.2-5                          base         62 k
 libedit           i386      3.0-2.20090923cvs.el5.art        atomic       80 k
 libtool-ltdl      i386      1.5.22-7.el5_4                   base         37 k
 mysql-libs        i386      5.1.57-1.el5.art                 atomic      2.1 M
 t1lib             i386      5.1.2-2.el5.art                  atomic      194 k
Updating for dependencies:
 php-cli           i386      5.3.6-3.el5.art                  atomic      2.6 M
 php-devel         i386      5.3.6-3.el5.art                  atomic      623 k
 php-imap          i386      5.3.6-3.el5.art                  atomic       82 k
 php-ldap          i386      5.3.6-3.el5.art                  atomic       52 k
 php-mbstring      i386      5.3.6-3.el5.art                  atomic      2.3 M
 php-mcrypt        i386      5.3.6-3.el5.art                  atomic       44 k
 php-mysql         i386      5.3.6-3.el5.art                  atomic      148 k
 php-odbc          i386      5.3.6-3.el5.art                  atomic       82 k
 php-pdo           i386      5.3.6-3.el5.art                  atomic      113 k
 php-snmp          i386      5.3.6-3.el5.art                  atomic       34 k
 php-xml           i386      5.3.6-3.el5.art                  atomic      207 k
 php-xmlrpc        i386      5.3.6-3.el5.art                  atomic       85 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install       8 Package(s)
Upgrade      13 Package(s)

Total download size: 12 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
(1/21): php-snmp-5.3.6-3.el5.art.i386.rpm                |  34 kB     00:00     
(2/21): libtool-ltdl-1.5.22-7.el5_4.i386.rpm             |  37 kB     00:00     
(3/21): php-mcrypt-5.3.6-3.el5.art.i386.rpm              |  44 kB     00:00     
(4/21): php-ldap-5.3.6-3.el5.art.i386.rpm                |  52 kB     00:00     
(5/21): libXmu-1.0.2-5.i386.rpm                          |  62 kB     00:00     
(6/21): libedit-3.0-2.20090923cvs.el5.art.i386.rpm       |  80 kB     00:00     
(7/21): php-odbc-5.3.6-3.el5.art.i386.rpm                |  82 kB     00:00     
(8/21): php-imap-5.3.6-3.el5.art.i386.rpm                |  82 kB     00:00     
(9/21): php-xmlrpc-5.3.6-3.el5.art.i386.rpm              |  85 kB     00:00     
(10/21): php-pdo-5.3.6-3.el5.art.i386.rpm                | 113 kB     00:00     
(11/21): php-mysql-5.3.6-3.el5.art.i386.rpm              | 148 kB     00:00     
(12/21): t1lib-5.1.2-2.el5.art.i386.rpm                  | 194 kB     00:00     
(13/21): php-gd-5.3.6-3.el5.art.i386.rpm                 | 205 kB     00:00     
(14/21): php-xml-5.3.6-3.el5.art.i386.rpm                | 207 kB     00:00     
(15/21): libXaw-1.0.2-8.1.i386.rpm                       | 324 kB     00:00     
(16/21): php-devel-5.3.6-3.el5.art.i386.rpm              | 623 kB     00:00     
(17/21): php-common-5.3.6-3.el5.art.i386.rpm             | 970 kB     00:00     
(18/21): php-5.3.6-3.el5.art.i386.rpm                    | 1.3 MB     00:00     
(19/21): mysql-libs-5.1.57-1.el5.art.i386.rpm            | 2.1 MB     00:00     
(20/21): php-mbstring-5.3.6-3.el5.art.i386.rpm           | 2.3 MB     00:00     
(21/21): php-cli-5.3.6-3.el5.art.i386.rpm                | 2.6 MB     00:00     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                           4.6 MB/s |  12 MB     00:02     
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Finished Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /etc/my.cnf from install of mysql-libs-5.1.57-1.el5.art.i386 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_4.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.57-1.el5.art.i386 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_4.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1250.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.57-1.el5.art.i386 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_4.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1251.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.57-1.el5.art.i386 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_4.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/czech/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.57-1.el5.art.i386 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_4.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/danish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.57-1.el5.art.i386 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_4.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/dutch/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.57-1.el5.art.i386 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_4.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.57-1.el5.art.i386 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_4.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/estonian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.57-1.el5.art.i386 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_4.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/french/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.57-1.el5.art.i386 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_4.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/german/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.57-1.el5.art.i386 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_4.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/greek/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.57-1.el5.art.i386 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_4.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/hungarian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.57-1.el5.art.i386 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_4.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/italian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.57-1.el5.art.i386 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_4.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/japanese/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.57-1.el5.art.i386 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_4.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/korean/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.57-1.el5.art.i386 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_4.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian-ny/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.57-1.el5.art.i386 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_4.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.57-1.el5.art.i386 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_4.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/polish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.57-1.el5.art.i386 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_4.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/portuguese/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.57-1.el5.art.i386 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_4.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/romanian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.57-1.el5.art.i386 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_4.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/russian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.57-1.el5.art.i386 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_4.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/serbian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.57-1.el5.art.i386 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_4.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/slovak/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.57-1.el5.art.i386 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_4.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/spanish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.57-1.el5.art.i386 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_4.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/swedish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.57-1.el5.art.i386 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_4.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/ukrainian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.57-1.el5.art.i386 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_4.1.i386

Error Summary
-------------
```

Thanks for your kind support.

Comment: The error summary is empty. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the commands:

```
# rpm -Uvh http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/latest.rpm
# yum --enablerepo=webtatic install php-gd
```

This should install php-gd library in your CentOS.